# Using multiple .war in one Web application

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

My company is creating multiple web applications that will have some overlap in functionality.  I want to develop the common functions a separate project, and since it would consist of web pages and managed beans I would assume the project would need to be in its own .war file.  I would then presumably deploy the two (or more) web applications inside of a .ear file.  Doing some preliminary research online has left me unsure of how well the web applications would work together.  Would I be able to share data between the managed beans and direct the user from pages inside of one web application to another?  Is the the proper approach to making my application maintainable or is there some better way to break up the project?

Comment: i would think all of the presentation would want to happen in a single war, but using frames you can render content from another war in your main war file.  The trick is using persistable business objects, to pass data between the two applications, via some kind of service bus.

Comment: Are the common functions web facing, or could they be developed in a jar and used as a dependency, then just shared that way between different webapps.

Comment: @aglassman The common functions would include web facing, capturing and showing user data across applications.  I figured I would use facelets templating to include the common content inside of application specific content.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon  Does that mean I would need to persist all of the data and then read it back from the database when shifting between pages in one web application to another?

Comment: Yes - well yes and no, with javascript and iframes (located within the same domain name) you can pass data between them using some nifty JScript techniques. However,  Service buses are designed to allow multiple applications a single entry point into interfacing with one another.  They all rely on the same database and sets of data; however, they use a persistence layer as well as service locators to ensure that the data remains constant between all apps.

Comment: Depending on the data, you have a few options.  You could store session data as a cookie, or some type of shared mem-cache, or in the database.  It really depends on how you want to balance between data security and performance.  If you want data security, go for database or mem-cache.  If you want performance, go mem-cache. If you want quick and dirty, go for cookies.

Comment: So what both of you are saying is that the two applications would not be able to access each others java objects to get data.  I would not be able to have managedBean1 in webApp1 makes calls to managedBean2 in webApp2 to get the data the user entered on the common screen.  That seems like a major failing in Jave EE if there is no elegant way to break apart a web application into multiple sub-applications.

Answer (score 1):

It is an overkill, but :
 you can split the functionality of your apps into DB, business logic and presentation /web/ tiers; The "overlapping" functionality can go to the business and DB tiers. 
The web fronts will have to talk to the business layer via corba, REST/LESS, soap or alternatives depending on what connectors you have in tier 2 /business/;

see [this diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Overview_of_a_three-tier_application_vectorVersion.svg/350px-Overview_of_a_three-tier_application_vectorVersion.svg.png)

 or google 3 tier architecture for more info

My company had the same problem some years ago, they ended up deploying multiple apps /some business logic duplication was inevitable /

Now we reinvented the wheel by creating a common, open, business layer service tier which can be called via webservices and is accessible to other apps/scripts anywhere within the department;

Comment: The only issue I have with such an approach is that there is web tier code I want to reuse across my applications.  There would be common data entry/presentation screens with common ManagedBeans and EJBs

Comment: you can probably use Vaadin to implement the common 'web tier' code. This way it will be rendered on the server /in your business layer/ and send back to the client.
Or simply move the common functionality to a new webapp, you can expose it later via webservices etc. if needed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your WAR files in to EAR file. And put library file in EAR so that all WAR files can share.

Comment: how this possible?